# excels index match for pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This been bugging me for a while now. How can I achieve `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E1&F1,B:B&C:C,0))`in python? This will return an error if not found.

So I started playing with the `pd.merge_asof`. But either way I try it only returns errors.

```
df_3 = pd.merge_asof(df_1, df_2, on=['x', 'y'], allow_exact_matches=False)
```

Would give the error:

```
pandas.tools.merge.MergeError: can only asof on a key for left
```

Edit:

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '5', '5', '5'], 
                   'y': ['smth1', 'smth2', 'smth1', 'smth2', 'smth1', 'smth2', 'smth1', 'smth1', 'smth2', 'smth3']})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['1', '2', '2', '3', '4', '5', '5'], 
                   'y': ['smth1','smth1','smth2','smth3','smth1','smth1','smth3'],
                   'z': ['other1','other1','other2','other3','other1','other1','other3',]})
```

So that's a sample, where I could simply do this in excel with above formula and get something like this:

```
x   y       z
1   smth1   other1
1   smth2   #NA
2   smth1   other1
2   smth2   other2
3   smth1   #NA
3   smth2   #NA
4   smth1   other1
5   smth1   other1
5   smth2   #NA
5   smth3   other3
```

So, is there an easy way to achieve the `INDEX MATCH` formula in excel in pandas?

Comment: Can you post some sample input data and expected results?

Comment: @ScottBoston sure, give me a moment :-)

Comment: @ScottBoston I updated the question with a sample. Sorry for the delay, got carried away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `merge` with `how='left'`:

```
df_1.merge(df_2, on=['x','y'], how='left')
```

Output:

```
   x      y       z
0  1  smth1  other1
1  1  smth2     NaN
2  2  smth1  other1
3  2  smth2  other2
4  3  smth1     NaN
5  3  smth2     NaN
6  4  smth1  other1
7  5  smth1  other1
8  5  smth2     NaN
9  5  smth3  other3
```